# Exception: "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestCompositionException: Workload definition 'wasm-tools': build net7.0 on mac

Tags: .net, .net-7.0

I have just installed net7.0 and created a new angular/c# web application.  When i try and build the app using VSCode, I've get an exception when trying to build a dotnet 7.0 application on a Mac:

Here is my dotnet info:

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.100
 Commit:    e12b7af219

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  11.4
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.11.0-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       d099f075e4

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.413 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.416 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.419 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.422 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.425 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.401 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.408 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.300 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.400 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.403 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  7.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.22 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.25 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.28 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.31 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.22 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.25 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.28 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.31 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

I have specifically removed all preview versions of net7.0.

I have also looked at this suggested fix (and tried rebooting after it) - but it doesn't work for me

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/478249/sdk-package-not-found-34microsoftnetsdkworkloadaut.html

I also get an exception if i try and open the solution with Visual Studio for Mac (17.5):

```
microsoft.net.sdk.workloadautoimportpropslocator
```

Answer (score 1):

this has been resolved for me by this article:

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/28947

Specifically, this part:

"Remove all folders in /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests", then reinstall SDKs you need.